# 2 Props passed to Child Component with a Map Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions

Hi how can I pass the Path into the map function! Have tried as nested array but can't get it

`Navbar` (parent component):

```
class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            nav: [{
                topic: 'Home',
                path: '/',
            },
            {
                topic: 'Bogen',
                path: '/Bogen'
            },
            ],
            topics: ['Home', 'Bogen', 'Projekt', 'Nutzer'],
            path: ['/', '/Bogen', '/Projekt', '/Nutzer'],
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='navbar'>
                <NavbarTopics topics={this.state.topics}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`NavbarTopics` (child component):

```
const NavbarTopics = (props) => (
    <ul className='ul_Ntopics'>
        {props.topics.map((topic, index) => <NavTopic topic={topic} key={index} />)}
    </ul>
)
```

`NavTopic` (child component):

```
const NavTopic = (props) => <li className='li_Ntopic'><Link className='Link_Ntopic' to=''>{props.topic}</Link></li>;

NavTopic.propTypes = {
    topic: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default NavTopic;
```

How can I pass the state path to the map-function, so that I can pass it as prop to NavTopic?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: [Works for me](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEzrNq) if I make seemingly-appropriate assumptions. We need an [mcve] in order to help you.

Comment: It works, but I can't do it. Pass the state'path' to navTopic. Do you have any advice or solution how I can do that?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "pass the state'path' to navTopic." Please add a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing topic as a prop, pass nav.

```
//Navbar
<NavbarTopics nav={this.state.nav}
```

Then iterate through nav array

```
// NavbarTopics
const NavbarTopics = (props) => (
  <ul className='ul_Ntopics'>
    {props.nav.map((nav, index) => <NavTopic nav={nav} key={index} />)}
  </ul>
)
```

In NavTopic,

```
const NavTopic = (props) => <li className='li_Ntopic'>
 <Link className='Link_Ntopic' to={props.nav.path}>{props.nav.topic}</Link>
</li>;
```